# What is purpose of "CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS" environment variable?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In  [core.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml)
for peer we can define env. variable as chaincodelistenaddress (CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS).

- what is purpose of this environment variable ?
- Can we use this variable for instead of DEV mode ?
- Currently I am trying to deploy network on Openshift platform. In this case when I set variable as CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS : peer01.local.com:7051 as same as CORE_PEER_ADDRESS :peer01.local.com:7051

> it gives me error as address already bind while starting peer container.

- If i assign different port CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS : peer01.local.com:7052

> it gives me error as can not assign address peer01.local.com:7052.

Comment: what fabric version is your peer running?

Answer (score 2):

This refers to the endpoint that the peer would listen to with regarding for the chaincode service.

Yes, you can use the variable when using dev-mode.

With regarding the errors - please specify your fabric version as things have changed slightly in the master branch.

In v1.0.0 (release branch), you can make your chaincode bind to the same port as the peer.

Also - please upload your core.yaml and the peer log for further information.
Alternatively you can seek advice in the fabric channel in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric

Comment: I am using fabric v1.0.2

Comment: My understanding from your input
CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS will only used to have separate service to communicate with chaincode container.

Is there any mechanism by which I can bind already created chaincode container to peer without using dev mode?

Comment: @user1598010 - ping me on https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric I'll try to help

Comment: > My understanding from your input CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS will only used to have separate service to communicate with chaincode container. 
----------------------------

No, you are far from the truth.